# Prevent file from being deleted but still be able to read it

Tags: vb.net

I have searched this a lot but still I couldn't find something useful basically I tried changing file permissions to deny the delete option and keep modification and so many other combinations.I want something to prevent file from being deleted but still allow me to read it I did this both manually and using vb.net this is the code I used(it is not mine btw)
lets say I have a text file already created I want that file to be read but not deleted by the user

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.AccessControl
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim filename As String = "C:\users\mbpc\desktop\test.txt"
    AddFileSecurity(filename, "Everyone", FileSystemRights.Delete, AccessControlType.Deny)
End Sub

Sub AddFileSecurity(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal account As String, _
    ByVal rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal controlType As AccessControlType)
    Dim fSecurity As FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName)
    Dim accessRule As FileSystemAccessRule = _
        New FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType)
    fSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule)
    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity)
End Sub

Sub RemoveFileSecurity(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal account As String, _
    ByVal rights As FileSystemRights, ByVal controlType As AccessControlType)
    Dim fSecurity As FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(fileName)
    fSecurity.RemoveAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(account, _
        rights, controlType))
    File.SetAccessControl(fileName, fSecurity)
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: read and delete are not the same thing. Does it allow you to delete after running the code?

Comment: no lets say i have a text file already created i want that file to be read but not deleted by  the user

Comment: read by any user?

Comment: yes by any user but can't delete it(and i am sorry if i am not clear enough i am still getting used to this site)

Comment: it can be done, however there is a bit to it, have you thought about just hiding the file? or even "locking" the folder it is coming from?

Comment: my friend i want this cuz i am making a file locker u see when the user chooses a file or folder to lock it will be hidden and its file permissions will be all denied so he can't access it.To unlock it u need another program which will show the file and change the file permsions to normal i want a way which will read this program but doesnt allow its deletion(and yes i can make it one program but i dont want to cuz i want it 2 be easier for the user 2 unlock his files/folders)